# Should I be concerned about thousands of write operations per minute?

Tags: soql, dml, largedatavolumes

I am setting up a POC which would create a junction between `User` and `Case` (using `Lookup` relationships only). We would have 10k+ users each touching several records per hour, so we might expect this table to be touched upwards of 1000 times per minute. We might purge records periodically; I could see cumulative table size topping 1 million records. SOQL should still perform just fine, as we would always filter on the two lookup fields and nothing else. However, architectural review has raised the number of write operations to this table as a potential cause for concern. Is this sort of volume problematic? What type of issues specifically do I need to worry about?

---

I have received a bit more detail about what specifically our architect is concerned about. Apparently, Customer-Centric Engineering may throttle our attempts to save records if our volume of DML Operations against a specific table is too high. Is it known at least within an order of magnitude how many transactions would typically cross this threshold?

Comment: Will you also have triggers/wf rules, etc. on your junction object? Also will be good to know what concerns have been raised around this, is it more around the time taken to perform DML operations?

Comment: Is Lookup Skew a potential issue here?
https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2013/04/managing-lookup-skew-to-avoid-record-lock-exceptions.html

Comment: Unlikely. A specific `User` would only view so many `Case` records, and vice versa.

Comment: If you look at tables like history or Share etc they would leave me to believe no issue with number of writes so long as you have no issues with locking rows